# How to filter WordPress home page posts by user role?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to filter home page blog posts by user role? My aim is to only display posts written by users of role type 'editor'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file in your theme's root folder and save it as `home.php` then paste following code in that file and you are done.

```
<?php
    get_header();
    $ids = get_users( array('role' => 'editor' ,'fields' => 'ID') );
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'author' => implode(',', $ids)
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            // code goes here, for example
            echo the_title() . '<br />'; // prints title of each post
        endwhile;
    endif;
    get_sidebar();
    get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet, much appreciated. Works wonderfully. May I suggest you include 'paged' in the query's args. That way next and previous page link will work. $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

Answer (score 1):

Under your home.php or front-page.php. add this following code:

```
<?php 

$args = array (
    'role' => 'influencer',
    'fields' => 'ID',
);

$user_ids = get_users($args);

$query_posts = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'author__in' => $user_ids
    )
);

var_dump($query_posts);
?>
```

Note: i just used the var_dump function to show post by author role. You can use the while loop and have_posts of wordpress or pure php loop